# Powershell - Convert MM/DD/YYYY to MySQL DateTime

Tags: powershell, date, datetime, data-conversion

How do you convert `03/16/2018` to `2018-03-16` without parsing as a string?

Comment: `03/16/2018` is a string?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
$date = '03/16/2018'
Get-Date $date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-Date '03/16/2018').ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```